# CF10 mod_jk.so won't load with RHEL 5.6 and Apache httpd 2.2.3

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, httpd, coldfusion

Does anyone have a solution to this... Running RHEL 5.6, with Apache httpd 2.2.3-65.el5_8 and get this error when trying to start the webserver:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 445 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf/mod_jk.conf: 
Cannot load /data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so into server: /data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so: undefined symbol: ap_get_server_description
```

I've looked all over Google, and there are some recommendations to compile my own connector, but I need the one from Adobe for CF10. Also the adobe site lists CF10 compatibility with Apache HTTPD 2.2.21, well with RedHat Enterprise they don't move the version number up, it gets reverse patched in the repository. ANY help would be awesome.

We are 50 days from going live with CF10 (or planning to), and really could use some help on getting this issue resolved.

In response to one of the posters here, I have indeed verified I'm using the x64 connector in my x64 OS based system.

Output requested by Eric:

```
undefined symbol: ap_server_root        (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_pool_cleanup_null (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_hash_get  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_get_server_name    (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_strerror  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_hook_child_init    (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_stat      (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_table_elts        (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_os_escape_path     (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_finalize_request_protocol  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mo                                        d_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_pool_cleanup_register     (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mo                                        d_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_global_mutex_create       (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mo                                        d_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_rflush     (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_get_server_description     (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mo                                        d_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_thread_detach     (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_itoa      (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_global_mutex_child_init   (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mo                                        d_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_array_push        (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_sub_req_lookup_uri (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_pool_create_ex    (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_filepath_merge    (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_date_parse_http   (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_destroy_sub_req    (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_mpm_query  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_sockaddr_info_get (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_get_server_port    (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_table_make        (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_global_mutex_lock (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_thread_create     (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff67fc000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b408b6f1000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b408b90c000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003ab2a00000)
undefined symbol: ap_set_last_modified  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_file_open (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_pvsprintf (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_hook_post_config   (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_pstrndup  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_pool_userdata_get (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_time_now  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_hook_handler       (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_hash_set  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_check_cmd_context  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_pool_clear        (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_rwrite     (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_psprintf  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_get_status_line    (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_palloc    (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_add_common_vars    (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_file_write        (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_table_setn        (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_off_t_toa (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_open_piped_log     (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_table_add (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_hook_type_checker  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_array_pstrcat     (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_run_default_port   (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_getword_conf       (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_add_version_component      (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mo                                        d_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_log_error  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_file_inherit_set  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_should_client_block        (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mo                                        d_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_pool_userdata_set (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_sleep     (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_pstrdup   (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_get_client_block   (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_set_content_type   (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_table_get (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_get_remote_host    (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_server_root_relative       (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mo                                        d_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_hash_make (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_setup_client_block (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_content_type_tolower       (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mo                                        d_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_find_path_info     (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: unixd_set_global_mutex_perms  (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mo                                        d_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_table_set (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_pstrcat   (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_no2slash   (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: ap_update_mtime       (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_array_make        (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_global_mutex_unlock       (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mo                                        d_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_uri_unparse       (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
undefined symbol: apr_sockaddr_ip_get   (/data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so)
```

Comment: could you post ouput of ldd -r /data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so

Comment: Do you really need their `mod_jk`?  Is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: Shane, yes I do need their particular version, they have modified it for previous code compatibility w/ CF9.

Comment: Eric, I will soon as I get back in the office Monday.

Comment: Output for Eric appended to original question.

Comment: SOLUTION: From adobe posted.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*moving solution from OP*</sub>

Here's the response and resolution from Adobe

You may download the connector from the following ["RHEL_mod_jk.zip" web-link](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/rhel-connector-configuration.html)

Please note that you may proceed with the installation choosing not to configure the web server initially. Once CF is installed you may proceed to create the connector using the wsconfig tool at `<root>\ColdFusion10\cfusion\runtime\bin`. Find the instructions at [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd9.html)

Once the connector is in place you may simply navigate to `<root>\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\<magic_number>` folder and replace the `mod_jk.so` file with downloaded copy and restart Apache.